# User - Feedback Implementation - Create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have implemented the following

user.rb

```
  has_many :authored_feedbacks, :class_name => "Feedback", :foreign_key => "author_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :received_feedbacks, -> { order("id DESC")}, :class_name => "Feedback", :foreign_key => "recipient_id", :dependent => :destroy
```

feedback.rb

```
  belongs_to :author, :foreign_key => :author_id, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :listing
```

feedbacks_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @author = current_user
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    @recipient = @listing.user
    @feedback = Feedback.new

    @feedback_presenter = FeedbackPresenter.new(@listing)
  end

  def create
    @author = current_user
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    @recipient = @listing.user

    @feedback = @author.authored_feedbacks.build(listing_id: @listing.id, author_id: @author.id, recipient_id: @recipient.id, rating: params[:feedback][:rating], comment: params[:feedback][:comment])
    if @feedback.save
      flash[:notices] = ["Feedback successfully submitted"]
      redirect_to user_feedbacks_path(@user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

    private

  def feedback_params
    params.require(:feedback).permit! (just ensure it's not a whitelist issue)
  end
```

from listings/show.html.erb I link to create a new Feedback:

```
<%= link_to 'Leave feedback for this user', new_user_feedback_path(@user, @feedback, listing_id: @listing.id, author_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: @listing.user.id) %>
```

feedbacks/new.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for [@author, @feedback], url: user_feedbacks_path(@author, @feedback) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :rating %>
    <%= f.select(:rating, @feedback_presenter.feedback_options, {}, id: 'rating', class: 'form-control') %>
    <%= f.label :comment %>
    <%= f.text_field :comment, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit Feedback", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
```

I am happy with the association setup and believe I am passing all the required params but as it stands I creating any feedback records. I am unsure where I am going wrong here so wanted to ask here on SO.

Edit - Added server output:

```
Started POST "/users/5/feedbacks" for ::1 at 2016-03-10 22:53:02 +0800
Processing by FeedbacksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"48PdNPwx3Dbusm+4H7n87+PvUFRCJUTxLAfiaMwxvAxFQww6YVUn3j5fChwGhwqHSc0ARuo+i5h+p8QvC8vw+A==", "feedback"=>{"rating"=>"Positive", "comment"=>"312435"}, "commit"=>"Submit Feedback", "user_id"=>"5"}
  Listing Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1/feedbacks/new?listing_id=5&recipient_id=1
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: You've defined `feedback_params` but aren't actually using it in the controller action. Is it possible that there's something that would be provided by that method which is missing since it's not being used, and the object is therefore failing validations? Also, any chance you could post the output from your server console that appears when you submit the form?

Comment: The validations where my first thought  so I have removed them to make it simpler. Now able to create some feedbacks in the console and it appears  # validates_presence_of :rating, message: "Your feedback must have a rating" & # validates_presence_of :comment, message: "Your feedback must have a comment" where causing issues. Creating via the Controller still giving me issues though. Will come back to this in the morning!